# Customer specific Environment variables in .Net Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-deployment, environment

I am writing a software "package" that can be used (more or less) as a stand-alone component by different companies. However there are some data (strings) in the application which I would like to be differentiated both between environments but also between customers.

So I will end up deploying these kind of configurations:

Customer 1 - Development,
Customer 1 - Production

Customer 2 - Development,
Customer 2 - Test,
Customer 2 - Production

Customer 3 - Development,
Customer 3 - UAT,
Customer 3 - Pre-Prod,
Customer 3 - Production

and so on...

In an old wcf project I would probably just make a different web.config for each configuration, but I am not sure how to achieve this here or if there is a more "correct" way of doing it. Is Environment Variables the way to go here or maybe appsettings or something completely different such as multiple different support projects... I would of course like to avoid maitaining multiple code bases as the code in the project is 100% identical for each customer.

Thanks!

Peter

Comment: what sort of application is your package intended for? would asp.net core built-in config management do? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1. Also, do you run it on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Are customers dynamic or they will be added once?

Comment: Timur: its a web api. 
Zhuber: customers are only dynamic in the sense of deploy. Each release will only have one customer (though possibly separate environments for that customer).

Comment: In this particular solution I would use Environment variables, advantages are that each customer can maintain there own environment settings, and they in turn can have different settings per environment. You won't have to worry about any kind of transforms when you deploy too. Look as what asp.net core does with dev/production environment variables. I would go that way.